# Trouble: bad swipe in ViewPager with updated Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2, swipe

**Good day!**

I have a problem with new GP Services.
We have: ViewPager with 3 elements. Middle element has structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            />
  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Within if we swipe from the border of the screen - everything works good. Else - nothing is happened.
Other elements (without map) in both cases works as its should work.

Problem appear with new Google Play Services (from **2013-08-06**). With version **3.1.59** all is OK.
Who know how determine this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try

```
uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

and it work!